# Activity getting relaunched after onPause getting called

Tags: android

I have splashActivity which are performing some task and then launching another activity . Once I am on SplashActivity and when FragmentLauncher get called ,and then I am pressing home button . App is relaunching splashscreen and then going to the activity. 
When home button is pressed app should not be automatically relaunched ,this is what i want

Comment: can you show your relevant code >

Answer (score 0):

Use a flag to check is splash screen is already shown and save the flag in PreferenceUtils to save the state. I think it will help you, if I am not wrong.

Answer (score 0):

You can try with calling method finish(); just after the startActivity(intent) in your splash screen.